# How do I get this to work in React Native ( Logic )

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Sorry to be so vague, Im a beginner at react-native literally started learning it less than a week ago. I'm not getting an error, but I basically want when I press start for it to go through all the workouts and tell you how many reps there are, and let you remove 1 set each time you press a button. But the issue is for some reason the relationship between workouts and dummyWorkouts is weird. Anything helps! For example when

```
dummyWorkouts is [
{Object},
{Object}
]
workouts is [
{Object},
{Object},
{Object},
{Object}
]
```

but with the default ones, I think there's an issue when I set dummyWorkouts to workouts. If there's a better way to do that it would be **very helpful** another big issue it's been having is that when it's going through the list of workouts one by one. It's limiting it to 2.

The part below to be specific

```
setCurrentSets(currentSets-1)
if(currentSets == 1){
   if(dummyWorkouts.length > 1){
        setCurrentWorkout(dummyWorkouts[1])
        setCurrentSets(dummyWorkouts[1].sets)
        var index = dummyWorkouts.indexOf(dummyWorkouts[0])
        setDummyWorkouts(dummyWorkouts.splice(index, 1))
     }else{
        setDummyWorkouts(workouts)
        setCurrentWorkout(workouts[0])
        setCurrentSets(workouts[0].sets)
        setWorkout(false)
   }
}
```

````
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/header';
import Workouts from './components/workouts';
import AddWorkout from './components/addWorkout';

export default function App() {
  const [workout, setWorkout] = useState(false);

  const [workouts, setWorkouts] = useState([
    { name: 'Pushups', key: '1', sets: '3', reps: '20' },
    { name: 'Test', key: '2', sets: '3', reps: '20' },
  ]);

  const [currentWorkout, setCurrentWorkout] = useState(workouts[0]);
  const [currentSets, setCurrentSets] = useState(3)
  const [dummyWorkouts, setDummyWorkouts] = useState();

  const pressHandler = (key) => {
    setWorkouts((prevWorkouts) => {
      return prevWorkouts.filter(workout => workout.key != key);
    })
  }

  const submitHandler = (text) => {
    if(text.length > 0){
      if(text.length <= 40){
        setWorkouts((workouts) => {
        return [
          { name: text, key: Math.random().toString(), reps: '10', sets: '3' },
          ...workouts
        ]
    })
      }else {Alert.alert('Whoops!', "You entered over 40 characters! Shorten it up a bit!", [{text: 'Close '}])}
    }else {Alert.alert('Whoops!', "You haven't entered anything!", [{text: 'Close '}])}
  }

  if(workout == false){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <View style={styles.WorkoutButton}>
        <Button
          title='START'
          color='white'
          onPress={()=>{
            if(workouts.includes(workouts[0])){
              setDummyWorkouts([...workouts])
              setWorkout(true)
            }else{Alert.alert('Whoops!', "No workouts detected!", [{text: 'Close '}])}
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <AddWorkout submitHandler={(val) => {submitHandler}}/>
        <View style={styles.list}> 
          <FlatList 
            data={workouts}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Workouts item={item} pressHandler={pressHandler} />
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );}else if (workout == true  && workouts.includes(workouts[0])){
    return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <View style={styles.WorkoutButton}>
        <Button
          title='-'
          color='white'
          onPress={() => {
            setCurrentSets(currentSets-1)
            if(currentSets == 1){
              if(dummyWorkouts.length > 1){

                setCurrentWorkout(dummyWorkouts[1])
                setCurrentSets(dummyWorkouts[1].sets)
                var index = dummyWorkouts.indexOf(dummyWorkouts[0])
                setDummyWorkouts(dummyWorkouts.splice(index, 1)) //delete workout
              }else{
                setDummyWorkouts(workouts)
                setCurrentWorkout(workouts[0])
                setCurrentSets(workouts[0].sets)
                setWorkout(false)
              }
            }
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.WorkoutCard}>
        <Text style={styles.Workout}>
          {currentWorkout.name}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.Sets}>
          Sets Left
          {'\n'}
          {currentSets}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.Reps}>
          Reps
          {'\n'}
          {currentWorkout.reps}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    );}else{
        setWorkout(false)
        Alert.alert('Whoops!', "No workouts detected!", [{text: 'Close '}])
      }
}

//Style Sheet

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#3B3B3B',
  },
  content: {
    padding: 60,
    flex: 1,
  },
  list: {
    marginTop: 20,
    flex:1,
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',

  },
  WorkoutButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    left: 140,
    bottom: 52,
    marginHorizontal: 150,
    borderRadius: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  WorkoutCard: {
    backgroundColor: 'crimson',
    height: 600,
    width: 300,
    marginTop: 50,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
  Workout: {
    fontSize: 50,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  Sets: {
    fontSize: 50,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    top: 30,
  },
  Reps: {
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    top: 50,
  },
});```
````

Comment: Can you specify what is the relationship between dummyworkouts and workouts

Comment: DummyWorkouts is basically meant to be a copy of workouts that I can edit without messing up actual workouts

Comment: can you specify what is the problem, i didnt get it.

Comment: I already answered the problem in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This project was later given up on, the issue at hand was copying dummyWorkouts (an array). It had to do something that I feel was more lower end other than my programming, and it's still beyond my expertise.

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to mark "the project was abandoned" as an answer. One of the main goals of SO is to help future developers with similar problems; by accepting this as the answer, you're explicitly saying to those devs that the best path forward is to give up on the whole project. Downvoting.

Comment: @Tom I understand that, but honestly I'm not so sure what to do. (I came back after months and found myself banned from asking questions on stackoverflow, I'm doing my best to fix my reputation.) These questions are some of the things that have dragged down my reputation, and I need to fix that.

Comment: Your best ways to get some initial reputation may be to answer questions or edit questions and answers. Using the site wrong to dig yourself out of a reputation hole is ultimately going to be counter-productive. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: I would suggest that one way to make this question a net-positive for you would be to post an actual solution. This answer suggests that you did figure it out, but you don't go into any detail, so future devs will get zero value from it. If you learned enough about the problem to write that answer, do so! You'll get my upvote, and maybe others'.